# Powerquery - Algorithm required for this task

Tags: algorithm, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Long time lurker, first time poster. Apologies in advance if my question appears a bit noobish.

I am new to powerquery/powerbi and trying to develop a report to solve a small logistics issue we are facing.

I have a list of cables that are given to our technicians to use of different pre-terminated lengths which they will use for their application. Ideally the closest length cable to the length of the route should be utilized, however that is not always the case. I want to match the cables issued to the routes (Column "Actual Cables Utilised"). Example below:

Cables issued:

[image: Cables isuued]

Breakdown:

[image: Breakdown]

Highlighted in green are the accepted substitutions. Red is the wrong substitution (There isn't a cable issued that is longer than the route).

I cannot find a way to run a loop in powerquery that would populate the breakdown table based on the issued table. Please note that unfortunately, my company does not allow python or r-script on our computers, so I am limited to basic power query.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is underdetermined. You can populate the breakdown table in many different ways and with many more wrong substitutions. What you show is just the one solution with the maximum number of accepted solutions.

Comment: I understand that you're not really interested in following up on this querstion.

Comment: Hi Peter. The loop that am looking for would have the "Cable lengths" table ordered by length as shown. The loop would compare the route length to the cable length and choose the first cable length longer than the route. Then decrease the "available" quantity of that cable length while assigning it to the route. IIf the quantity of the optimal cable length is zero. it will move to the next one. In case there is no available suitable cable length, I would like it to leave it empty and move on to the next route.

Answer (score 1):

This might work

- Group the Breakdown table by technician
- For each technician, generate a list of Issued cables with an entry for each cable (i.e. if there are 2 - 40m cables, 40 will appear twice in the list.

  - *The Issued cables will be assigned sequentially in the order presented by the Breakdown sheet.*
- Use a recursive function that, as it generates the Utilized cable list, removes that entry from the Issued cables.

***Main Code***

```
let

//Read in the Issued and Breakdown tables
//Change the Source lines to reflect your own data sources for these tables
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Issued"]}[Content],
    Issued = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source1), each {_, Int64.Type})),

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Breakdown"]}[Content],
    Breakdown = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Technician", type text}, {"Route Length (m)", Int64.Type}, {"Ideal Cable Length (m)", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by Technician
// Generate a list of cables where there is one entry for every issued cable
// Then call the custom (recursive) function to generate an appropriate list for each tech
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Breakdown, {"Technician"}, {
        {"Cables", (t)=> 
            let
             cables = List.Combine(
                List.Generate(
                    ()=> [c=List.Repeat({Issued[Cable Lengths]{0}}, Table.Column(Issued, t[Technician]{0}){0}), idx=0],
                    each [idx] < Table.RowCount(Issued),
                    each [c=List.Repeat({Issued[Cable Lengths]{[idx]+1}}, Table.Column(Issued, t[Technician]{0}){[idx]+1}), idx = [idx]+1],
                    each [c])),
             x = fnBreakdown(t, cables)
            in
                x, type list}}),
    #"Expanded Cables" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Cables"),

//add the utilized cable column back to the Breakdown table
    #"Breakdown Table" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(Breakdown) & {#"Expanded Cables"[Cables]},
        type table[Technician=text, #"Route Length (m)"=Int64.Type, 
            #"Ideal Cable Length (m)"=Int64.Type,Actual Cable Utilized=Int64.Type]
    )
in
    #"Breakdown Table"
```

***Custom Function** 
rename fnBreakdown*

```
//Rename this query "fnBreakdown"

//tech = the subtable all with the same technician
//cables = a list of cables with a single entry for each size
//   generated by List.Repeat in the original call from the main code
//cableList = a list of the utilized cable
//Index is the index into the Tech table

(tech as table, cables as list, optional cableList as list, optional Index as number)=>

let

//set intial values for optional arguments
    idx = if Index = null then 0 else Index + 1,
    cableL = if cableList = null then {} else cableList,

//determine cable matching for "idx"th entry
//if there is no match then write a null
    #"New Cab" = List.Select(cables, each _ >= tech[#"Route Length (m)"]{idx}),
    #"New Cable" = if #"New Cab" = {} then null else #"New Cab"{0},

//Remove the used cable from the list of "cables"
    #"New Cables" = if List.PositionOf(cables,#"New Cable",Occurrence.First) = -1 
        then cables 
        else List.RemoveRange(cables,List.PositionOf(cables,#"New Cable",Occurrence.First),1),

//new cable list for this tech
    #"New Cable List" = cableL & {#"New Cable"},

//if we haven't checked all the routes then recursively call the function with the updated arguments
    result = if idx < Table.RowCount(tech)-1 
                then  fnBreakdown(tech,#"New Cables", #"New Cable List", idx)
                else #"New Cable List"
in 
    result
```

***Results from your data above***
[image]